# clojure when-let alternative for an empty array?

Tags: clojure

I'm generating json as literally as I can in clojure. My problem is that certain branches of the json are only present if given parameters are given. Here is a sample of such a condition

```
(defn message-for
  [name uuid & [generated-uuids]]
  {:message {:id             (generate-uuid)
             :details        {:name name}
             :metadata       {:batch (merge {:id uuid}
                                            (when generated-uuids (let [batches (map #(array-map :id %) generated-uuids)]
                                                                            {:generatedBatches batches})))}}})
```

Unfortunately the when/let part is quite ugly. This same could be achieved using when-let as following but it doesn't work because my map returns [] instead of a nil.

```
(defn message-for
  [name uuid & [generated-uuids]]
  {:message {:id             (generate-uuid)
             :details        {:name name}
             :metadata       {:batch (merge {:id uuid}
                                            (when-let [batches (map #(array-map :id %) generated-uuids)]
                                                           {:generatedBatches batches}))}}})
```

Any ideas if I could somehow make when-let consider an empty list/array/seq as false so I could clean up my code a bit?

Comment: obviously, you know that :generatedBatches key will not be created if generated-uuids is empty. And you do check the emptyness of generated-uuids in your first solution. So, you can make your first solution shorter like this (when (seq generated-uuids)
  {:generatedBatches (map #(array-map :id %) generated-uuids)})

Answer (score 4):

`not-empty` returns its argument if it is not empty.

When using `when-let` with a collection, always use `not-empty`

- to retain the collection type
- make refactoring easier
- expressivenes

  ```
  (when-let [batches (not-empty (map ...))]
    ...)
  ```

In your case I'd however prefer something like this:

```
...
:metadata {:batch (cond-> {:id uuid}
                       (seq generated-uuids)
                       (assoc :generatedBatches (map ...)))}
...
```

Notice that all three of the advantages listed above where met, without a nested `let`.

Also notice a new advantage

- easier to extend with more conditions lateron

Answer (score 1):

`seq` returns nil on an empty input sequence so you could do:

```
(when-let [batches (seq (map #(array-map :id %) generated-uuids))]
             {:generatedBatches batches}))}}})
```